# Checking if object is instance of a generic parent class

Tags: java, class, generics, inheritance, runtime

I have a class I am obtaining by using *Class.forName* like this

```
Class<?> processClass = Class.forName(entity.getClassname());
```

I need to know if ***processClass*** is an instance of this type

```
(Class<? extends Job>)
```

How can I check this in Java? I mean I need to do something like this:

```
            if (processClass.isAssignableFrom((Class<? extends Job>))){
                ....
            }
```

How can that be achieved in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to test

```
Job.class.isAssignableFrom(processClass)
```

Comment: Ok, I correct myself. That checks what I want. Thanks!